# Wav file not getting loaded in safari on mac

Tags: php, audio, safari

I'm trying to serve a WAV file using PHP, and I want it to play rather than download. I'm setting up the headers like this:

```
$path = "wav.wav";
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: audio/wav");
header("Content-Duration: 00:00:22.046");
readfile($path);
exit();
```

this works perfectly on chrome, IE, firefox, but not on safari 9 on mac (safari 8 did work). When I test I get no response headers at all!

this is a test link you can see for yourself:
http://staging-new-play.idomoo.com/couchbase_test/t3.php

any ideas?

Comment: In my experience when a file tries to download rather than autoplay it usually means that the machine doesn't know what to do with it. Does the computer you're testing Safari with have WAV files registered to play with a certain app?

Comment: yes, safari does usually play wav files

Comment: What was the answer for getting Mac Safari to play audio files?

Comment: I finally got mine working here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796154/470749

Answer (score 1):

you need to send partial content

```
$file = "wav.wav";
$bufferSize = 2097152;

$filesize = filesize($file);
$offset = 0;
$length = $filesize;
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_RANGE"])) {
    preg_match("/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/", $_SERVER["HTTP_RANGE"], $matches);
    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $end = $matches[2] || $matches[2] === "0" ? intval($matches[2]) : $filesize - 1;
    $length = $end + 1 - $offset;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $offset-$end/$filesize");
}
header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($file));
header("Content-Length: $filesize");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
$file = fopen($file, "r");
fseek($file, $offset);
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
while ($length >= $bufferSize)
{
    print(fread($file, $bufferSize));
    $length -= $bufferSize;
}
if ($length) print(fread($file, $length));
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari needs [`Content-Range:`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16) in order to play `wav` files.

Add this line:

```
header("Content-Range: something");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to drop some unnecessary headers (`Accept-Ranges` and `Connection`) and add a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header:

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
header("Content-Type: audio/wav");
header("Content-Duration: 00:00:22.046");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```